# Elementwise multiplication ignoring certain rows of a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Let's say I have a matrix like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [89, 43, 2], [12, -3, 4], [-2, 4, 7]])

array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [89, 43,  2],
       [12, -3,  4],
       [-2,  4,  7]])
```

and a vector that looks like this:

```
b = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

If I now want to do a elementwise multiplication I can simply do

```
c = a * b
```

and obtain

```
array([[ 1,  4,  9],
       [89, 86,  6],
       [12, -6, 12],
       [-2,  8, 21]])
```

My question is: How can I do this kind of multiplication only for certain rows in my matrix? I currently do it like this:

```
E = a.copy()

# ignore these rows
ignInd = [1, 3]

for ind in xrange(a.shape[0]):
    if ind not in ignInd:
        E[ind, :] = a[ind, :] * b
```

The matrix `E` looks as desired (the rows 1 and 3 are the same as in `a`):

```
array([[ 1,  4,  9],
       [89, 43,  2],
       [12, -6, 12],
       [-2,  4,  7]])
```

Can someone come up with a smarter solution than this?

Comment: Maybe extend the vector to a matrix with some rows being all 1s?

Comment: @tobias_k:  This might work but the columns should be 1 not the rows. I try that, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you could just do the multiplication and then put back the original data where you want to ignore ...

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[89,43,2],[12, -3, 4], [-2, 4, 7]])
>>> b = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> c = a * b
>>> ignInd = [1,3]
>>> c[ignInd, :]
array([[89, 86,  6],
       [-2,  8, 21]])
>>> c[ignInd, :] = a[ignInd, :]
>>> c
array([[ 1,  4,  9],
       [89, 43,  2],
       [12, -6, 12],
       [-2,  4,  7]])
```

Comment: Great, that is working nicely, too, thanks! I upvote it and might accept it later on, depending on other users' answers.

Comment: I wasn't hoping this to be fast given it does many multiplications that are over-written, but interestingly some runtime tests I did show this to be really fast! Interesting stuff really.

Answer (score 4):

You can index an NumPy array directly with another NumPy array. In your case, you have the indexes of rows you want to ignore, so you can build an array of indexes to *include* from this:

```
In [21]: ignInd = [1,3]   #ignore these rows
In [22]: ind = np.array([i for i in range(a.shape[0]) if i not in ignInd])
In [23]: E2 = a.copy()

In [24]: E2[ind,:] = a[ind,:]*b

In [25]: E2
Out[25]: 
array([[ 1,  4,  9],
       [89, 43,  2],
       [12, -6, 12],
       [-2,  4,  7]])
```

EDIT: as @DSM comments, for large arrays it would be more efficient to build the index array using NumPy's vectorized methods, viz. `ind = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(len(a)), ignInd)` instead of the list comprehension used above.

Comment: That works fine, thanks! I upvote it and might accept it late ron, depending on the quality of other answers.

Comment: Note that you could get `ind` using vector ops, like `np.setdiff1d(np.arange(len(a)), ignInd)`, but it doesn't matter much when the lists are so small here.

Comment: @DSM: Thanks for this comment! In reality, my arrays are of course much larger so I will use your suggestion to determine ind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) with [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to select the rows excluded in the give indices list. The implementation would look something like this -

```
E = a.copy()
mask = ~np.in1d(np.arange(a.shape[0]),ignInd,)
E[mask] = a[mask]*b
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine as well. I upvote it and might accept it later on, depending on the quality of other answers.

Comment: @Cleb No rush at all! Just curious, what are the datasizes of the inputs?

Comment: Depends, but usually something like 2000*2000 matrices. And I have to do these calculations many many times so speed really matters.

Answer (score -1):

For the 1st row in **a**

```
a[0] = a[0] * b
```

..and so on for the other rows.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not solve the question; that is what I do in my for-loop and the "and so on" is actually the crucial part.

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding your question. You can directly access any of the rows using the index for that row.

Comment: No problem, I always appreciate input :)